# Criar JSON a partir de Select do banco

Tags: php, json

Populei um banco mysql com dados neste formato:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
 e queria retornar isso em json usando php, o problema é que eu tenho por exemplo varias linhas com o mesmo estado, e preciso retornar o json enste formato:

```
    {
  "Estados": {
    "Espirito Santo": {
      "Cidades": {
        "Cidade 1": {
          "Nome Unidade": {
            "Nome": "a",
            "Endereco": "b",
            "log": "222",
            "lat": "111"
          },
          "Nome Unidade2": {
            "Nome": "a",
            "Endereco": "b",
            "log": "222",
            "lat": "111"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ou seja, agrupar todos os estados repetidos, cidades tambem. não tenho ideia de como fazer, oque consegui até agora foi retirar o id e criar o array com os estados ( repetidos) assim:

```
$resultado = $this->sql->select("SELECT * FROM tb_unidades");
//print_r($resultado);
//print_r($resultado['0']['estado']);

$estados = array();
foreach ($resultado as &$row) {
    unset($row['id']);
    $estados[] = array($row['estado']);
}
$estados = array("Estados"=>$estados, "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
print_r(json_encode($estados));
```

EDIT:
Tentando a solução proposta obtive isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 $resultado = $this->sql->select("SELECT * FROM tb_unidades");

$estados = array();
$cidades = array();

foreach ($resultado as $row) {
    $cidades[$row["cidade"]][] = $row;
    $estados[$row["estado"]][] = $cidades;
}

$estadosp = array("Estados"=>$estados);
return json_encode($estadosp);
```

As cidades ficaram repetidas, e apareceu algumas de outros estados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá.

Use o estado como sendo a chave do array.

```
$resultado = $this->sql->select("SELECT * FROM tb_unidades");


$estados = array();
foreach ($resultado as $row) {

    $estados[$row["estado"]][$row["cidade"]][] = $row;
}
```

Dá um `print_r` nesse array e veja como ele fica.

Comment: Consegui criar os 2 array, de estados e de cidades sem repetir, ok, mas agora como coloco a cidade dentro do array estados?

Comment: Então, mas com apenas 1 array você consegue tudo isso.

Comment: confere meu edit, pelo que pensei, achei que as cidades iriram entrar como um novo array, mas na verdade misturou tudo

Comment: Oque é estranho pq quando printo apenas $cidades, me retorna corretamente

Comment: Veja o edit que fiz na resposta

Comment: Exatamente isso, obrigado

Comment: deu certo? se for o caso, adiciona mais 1 chave para o bairro, acredito que vai ficar melhor.

Comment: Para minha aplicação não acho necessário, é um combo box de cidade e estado